# Regex: How to find substring that does NOT contain a certain word

Tags: python, regex

I have this string;

```
string = "STARTcandyFINISH  STARTsugarFINISH STARTpoisonFINISH STARTBlobpoisonFINISH STARTpoisonBlobFINISH"
```

I would like to match and capture all substrings that appear in between `START` and `FINISH` but only if the word "poison" does NOT appear in that substring. How do I exclude this word and capture only the desired substrings?

```
re.findall(r'START(.*?)FINISH', string)
```

Desired captured groups:

```
candy
sugar
```

Comment: @Sraw I'm not sure if this is a duplicate because my question is about avoiding a word - not just a single character (please correct me if I'm wrong - thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tempered dot, we can try:

```
string = "STARTcandyFINISH  STARTsugarFINISH STARTpoisonFINISH STARTBlobpoisonFINISH STARTpoisonBlobFINISH"
matches = re.findall(r'START((?:(?!poison).)*?)FINISH', string)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['candy', 'sugar']
```

For an explanation of how the regex pattern works, we can have a closer look at:

```
(?:(?!poison).)*?
```

This uses a *tempered* dot trick.  It will match, one character at a time, so long as what follows is *not* `poison`.